# Apply force to a SCNSphere in the direction the back camera is pointing to

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have read many stackoverflow answer but none of have added sample code that I can get help from

I have tried

```
func createBall (with velocityMultiplier:Float = 0 ,touchLocation:CGPoint = .zero) {

    let geo = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
    var node = SCNNode(geometry: geo)
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    node = self.update(node, withGeometry: geo, type: .dynamic)
    node.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = true
    node.physicsBody?.allowsResting = true

    let (direction,position) = getUserVector()
    node.position = position
    node.simdTransform = (sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform)!

    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)


    let force = simd_make_float4(0, 0,-3,0)
    let rotatedForce = simd_mul((sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform)!, force)

    let vectorForce = SCNVector3(x:rotatedForce.x, y:rotatedForce.y, z:rotatedForce.z)


    node.physicsBody?.applyForce(vectorForce , asImpulse: true)

}
```

It is working fine Ball is thrown from centre

Here  If I change   Y or X position of  `let force = simd_make_float4(0, 2,-3,0)` Ball is not thrown from centre it is thrown of the screen

What I need is to apply Y and Z position to force any help is appreciated

Comment: The title of the question is quite unclear

Comment: @JoseRios What it could be ? Please suggest

Comment: I'm sorry but don't understand the question :-(
What do you mean with "user see to SCNNode"? is it "looks at" or "staring to" ?

Comment: @JoseRios I am creating demo where I have to throw the ball where user is pointing the device . With Added code in question i am able to do it by z position. But If I am trying to give Y position in `force`  matrix ball is going somewhere else rather than where user pointing.

Comment: I think i need to something with `simd_mul` but I am not that good in math to understand angles  :(

Comment: @JoseRios Do you know how to rotate a node to that angle so it always face user camera, For example on tap on screen I am adding a node which is a basket ball poll so the SCNTorus should always on user camera side ?